# Statically Linking DBD::Pg (against libpq.so) but Dynamically Against Perl?

Tags: perl, postgresql, static-linking, dbd, makemaker

I'm trying to build DBD::Pg on a linux host via the Makefile.PL; my requirements are such that I must be able to dynamically link against perl, but statically link against libpq.so (since it may not be available on all boxes).

Is there an easy way to do this? I have tried changing the link options in the LIBS directive of the Makefile.PL but MakeMaker ignores my options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you've mis-specified your requirements.

You do not need to statically link to `libpq` just because it might not be available on all systems.

What you should generally do instead is *dynamically link to `libq`* and either set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in  a wrapper script or use `rpath` linking so that `libpq` can be found.

Be aware though that whether statically or dynamically linking, if some other module loads a `libpq` into the same Perl you'll either get two incompatible `libpq`s linked into the same executable (boom) or one of the modules using a `libpq` other than the one it was compiled against (also boom). If you use rpath linking, `ld.so`'s awareness of link scopes might let you get away with it, but setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will almost certainly cause issues.

You might want to look into using `rpath` with `$ORIGIN`.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow your response; how can I guarantee that my module works at runtime (in terms of having the correct library)?

Comment: With `rpath` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Don't both just modify the search path for libraries in different ways? I'm saying that I want to build the module on box X (which has libpq) and run it on box Y (which has no libpq). Maybe I'm not following; I'm not super well versed on linking / compiling by any means.

Comment: @Blaskovicz You bundle `libpq.so` with your executable.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, trying to do static linking of `libpq` is not likely to solve your problem at large.

`libpq` itself is likely to depend on `libc` (`glibc`). If you link it statically, but other modules dynamically, it means you will have 2 copies of `libc`: one inside `libpq`, another referenced by Perl itself and loaded dynamically. This is very dangerous situation, especially if some procedure allocates memory using `malloc` and passes pointer back to caller. If you have memory allocated by malloc from one copy of `libc`, but `free`ed by another copy, your program (and Perl) will definitely crash.

In other words, if you want to go static, you *must* go all way through - everything, 100% must be compiled statically, so only one copy of `libc` used by your application. And the opposite is true - if you are dynamic, everything should be dynamic, as to only ever use one copy of `libc`. These rules don't apply only if your libraries do not use anything from `libc` (not even `sprintf`).

Even if you succeed at static `libpq` compilation and it will work (not very likely), what if `DBI` is not installed? I have seen enough Linux boxes where DBI is not present by default. Do you compile DBI statically then as well? What if `Perl` is not present (as unlikely this is on Linux), or if it is very old?

Proper solution is to install it using native OS package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbd-pg-perl   # Ubuntu/Debian
sudo yum install perl-DBD-Pg          # Redhat/Fedora
```

If you do not have root on hosts in question, maybe you should consider using `perlbrew` - install your own Perl in home directory. With this, you should be able to compile your own copy of `libpq` and link it with Perl provided by `perlbrew` dynamically.

Comment: Good explanation of the issues re static linking, +1